# Redirect all pages to homepage via .htaccess except backend

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, redirect, .htaccess, redirect-url

I've been trying to redirect all pages of my Magento website to homepage via .htaccess - except the backend, naturally. Currently, I'm using these rules and everything is working fine so far but I want to access my backend (*domain.com*/**office**):

```
# Redirect the all pages to homepage

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|fonts|gif|jpe?g?|png|ico) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=302,L]
```

Can someone help me with this? I've been trying many rules but none of them worked well. With some rules, when I try to access my backend, I'm still redirected to homepage. With other rules, I got a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` file containing only this should work (backup the original one):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/office
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php/office
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(css|fonts|gif|jpe?g?|png|ico|js) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/ [R=302]
```

roughly translates to:

- enable rewriting possibilities
- line 2: apply rewrite rule from line 6 if path is NOT /admin
- line 3: apply rewrite rule from line 6 if path is NOT /index.php/office (since
  you'll probably be redirected from /office to /index.php/office/...)
- line 4: apply rewrite rule from line 6 if path is NOT / (= homepage)
- line 5: if requested file ending is not one of ...
- line 6: definitely make it a **302** or else your customers might still go
  in circles once you revert back to the original `.htaccess` file...

Comment: Thank you so much, Christoph! I just changed a little bit your last line and it's working perfectly now for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}!^/office/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Abdul. However, I got a 500 - Internal Server Error...